# How do you display one line of text in bash

Tags: linux, bash, input, scripting

I'm trying to display only one line of text when executing my code in bash.
 So for example if I was to run the following

```
./myscript.sh /etc
```

it would display all the lines in my script EX:

```
/etc is a directory
etc/hosts is a file
/dev/tty0 is a character device
/dev/sda is a block device
/MyNonExistantDirectory is not a file, directory, character device or block device on your system.
```

What I want it to display is

```
/etc is a directory
```

after using the command `./myscript.sh /etc`.

```
#!/bin/bash
device0="/etc"
if [ -d "$device0" ]
then
echo "$device0 is a directory."
fi

device1="/etc/hosts"
if [ -f "$device1" ]
then
echo "$device1 is a file."
fi

device2="/dev/tty0"
if [ -c "$device2" ]
then
echo "$device2 is a character device."
fi

device3="/dev/sda"
if [ -b "$device3" ]
then
echo "$device3 is a block device."
fi

device4="/MyNonExistantDirectory"
if [ -f "$device4" ]
then
echo "$device4 is not a file, directory, character device or block device on your system."
fi
```

Comment: The argument to the script is in `$1`. Use that.

Comment: You are not using any parameters inside of your script. You are hard coding everything. How are you expecting that the IF conditions do not return true if everything is hard coded for it?

Answer (score 1):

Use `$1` to get the argument. And use `if/elif/else` to test mutually exclusive conditions.

```
#!/bin/bash
device=$1
if [ -d "$device" ]
then
    echo "$device is a directory."
elif [ -f "$device" ]
then
    echo "$device is a file."
elif [ -c "$device" ]
then
    echo "$device is a character device."
elif [ -b "$device" ]
then
    echo "$device is a block device."
else
    echo "$device is not a file, directory, character device or block device on your system."
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

You pretty much nailed it i think; all you need to do is make one "device" from the first positional argument ($1) and then convert your if statements per path into a single if statement with elif clauses.

```
#!/bin/bash
device=$1

if [ -d "$device" ]; then
    echo "$device is a directory."

elif [ -f $device ]; then
    echo "$device1 is a file."

elif [ -c $device ]; then
    echo "$device2 is a character device."

elif [ -b $device ]; then
    echo "$device3 is a block device."

else
    echo "$device is not a file, directory, character device or block device on your system."

fi
```

Answer (score 0):

the linux command head will show the top lines of a file. Therefore

```
head -1
```

I believe will produce the output you are looking for.

Comment: The OP wants *one* line of output, not necessarily the *first* line of the current output.

Comment: the desired output i see stated is the first line. sorry, i guess i am just dense.